# Single line when binding XmlDataProvider to ListView

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I want to show XmlData within a ListView. The XmlDataProvider is filled correctly but the Listview only shows the first line. What do I have to change to show all lines inside the XmlDocument?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <ListView Padding="4">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource xmlData}" XPath="*"/>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="Info" Width="256" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding XPath=Message}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

In code behind:

```
private void RefreshList(XmlDocument doc)
{
    XmlDataProvider provider = (XmlDataProvider)FindResource("xmlData");
    provider.Document = doc;
    provider.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `XmlData`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it this way:

1. Add XPath to XmlDataProvider
2. Using of Path=InnerText instead of XPath

See source below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlData" XPath="//Prototype"/>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource xmlData}" XPath="Message"/>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=InnerText}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```